# Post data from angular to node js route not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to send array `subjectAverage` to nodejs route. I am using express route, its showing unidentified when trying to print on console.

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", [])
app.controller("ListController2", ['$scope','getAverage','$http',function($scope, getAverage,$http)  {
 $scope.subjectAverages = [{
'subjectName': '',
'yearSem': '',
'studentsAppeared': '',
 'studentsPassed':'',
 'percentage':'',
 'average':'',
 'facultyComment':''
 }];


$scope.save=function(){

 var data =angular.toJson($scope.subjectAverages)
 var objectToSerialize={'object':data};
 $http({
    url: 'app',
    method: "POST",
    data: $.param(objectToSerialize),
    headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
}).success(function(data){
    alert("done");
});

}  
router.post('/app',function(res,req){
    console.log(req.body);
    });
```

Please guide.

Comment: Are you using express-bodyparser module in your node's app.js

Comment: yes i am using it.

Comment: Donot serialise the data using $.param. You cant send params in POST request. In the data part of your http request just send {object : $scope.subjectAverages}

Comment: i am getting the same error. no change

Comment: Aren't the parameters of your route the wrong way around? The documentation states the ordering is req,res.

Comment: @Gimby that ordering seems to be the problem its working now, it gave me trouble the whole day. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$scope.save=function(){

 var data = {object : $scope.subjectAverages};
 $http({
    url: '/app',
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(function(data){ //.success is deprecated,so use .then
    alert("done");
})
  .catch(function(err){//using .catch instead of .error as it is deprecated
    console.log("Error in request =>", err)
});
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan bro help me with this.

Comment: How are you using the bodyparser in the back end?

Comment: add these so that it can handle all types based on the headers in the request : app.use(bodyParser.json()); app.use(bodyParser.text()); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

Comment: it is sstill undefined. i have no idea why its not working.been trying different things since yesterday.

Comment: can you change the url to '/app' instead of 'app'

Comment: i did that but not working. in inspect element, inside network i can see post req with json data.

Comment: json-object:object:0:object

Comment: json   inside json   object:object  inside it  0:object  and data